# Flask global exception handling

Tags: flask

How could one handle exceptions globally with Flask? I have found ways to use the following to handle custom db interactions:

```
try:
    sess.add(cat2)
    sess.commit()
except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError, exc:
    reason = exc.message
    if reason.endswith('is not unique'):
        print "%s already exists" % exc.params[0]
        sess.rollback()
```

The problem with `try`-`except` is I would have to run that on every aspect of my code. I can find better ways to do that for custom code. My question is directed more towards global catching and handling for:

```
apimanager.create_api(
    Model,
    collection_name="models",
    **base_writable_api_settings
)
```

I have found that this `apimanager` accepts `validation_exceptions`: [`ValidationError`] but I have found no examples of this being used.

I still would like a higher tier of handling that effects all db interactions with a simple concept of "If this error: show this, If another error: show something else" that just runs on all interactions/exceptions automatically without me including it on every `apimanager` (putting it in my `base_writable_api_settings` is fine I guess). (`IntegrityError`, `NameError`, `DataError`, `DatabaseError`, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to set up an error handler on the app that formats the exception into a json response.  Then you can create custom exceptions like UnauthorizedException...

```
class Unauthorized(Exception):
    status_code = 401

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def _(error):

    trace = traceback.format_exc()
    status_code = getattr(error, 'status_code', 400)
    response_dict = dict(getattr(error, 'payload', None) or ())
    response_dict['message'] = getattr(error, 'message', None)
    response_dict['traceback'] = trace

    response = jsonify(response_dict)
    response.status_code = status_code
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
    return response
```

You can also handle *specific* exceptions using this pattern...

```
@app.errorhandler(ValidationError)
def handle_validation_error(error):
    # Do something...
```

Error handlers get attached to the app, not the apimanager.  You probably have something like

```
app = Flask()
apimanager = ApiManager(app) 
...
```

Put this somewhere using that app object.

Comment: [Here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) is the relevant documentation!

Comment: Could you please tell me how to connect this to:

apimanager.create_api(
    Model,
    collection_name="models",
    **base_writable_api_settings)

Currently my goal is to get a custom message for: IntegrityError. That applies to all api_managers.


`code
base_api_settings = {
    "exclude_columns": ['password', 'user.password', 'groups',
                        'registration_token', 'user.registration_token'],
    "max_results_per_page": 100,
    "validation_exceptions": [ValidationError]
}`

Comment: I have tried this several different ways. Each time I submit a duplicate entry I get the standard:

{
  "message": "IntegrityError"
}

Here is a pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/7Asb08kE

Comment: Thank you for your help btw. This has been a very annoying addition to my framework lol.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach uses [decorated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) view-functions.

You could define a decorator like the following:

```
def handle_exceptions(func):
  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    except ValidationError:
      # do something
    except HTTPException:
      # do something else ...
    except MyCustomException:
      # do a third thing
```

Then you can simply decorate your view-functions, e.g.

```
@app.route('/')
@handle_exceptions
def index():
  # ...
```

I unfortunately do not know about the hooks Flask-Restless offers for passing view-functions.